# unable to get timestamp for a particular file

Tags: python

I am unable to get the timestamp for a file in a loop.

```
flpath=path+f   
fltm=os.path.gettime(flpath)
filetm=datetime.timestamp(fltm) 
return filetm
```

trying to get file's created/modified time so that it can be used to validate and move the file accordingly.

getting the following error:

```
flpath= **/Source/Pdf.pdf <class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 54, in <module>
    ftm=fileTM(f)
  line 28, in fileTM
    fltm=os.path.gettime(flpath)
AttributeError: module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'gettime'
```

Comment: `gettime` does not exist... try: `getatime` for access time (if supported), `getmtime` for modification time, or `getctime` for creation time of the file. Alternately, call `os.stat(fpath).st_atime # or .st_mtime or .st_ctime`

Comment: Read the docs! https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime

Answer (score 1):

you can get timestamp from a file in python by doing this , [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-creation-and-modification-date-time-of-a-file-using-python#:%7E:text=The%20stat()%20function%20gives,datetime%20object%20using%20the%20datetime.) is the reference

```
import os
import datetime

# Specify the file path
file_path = 'file.js'

# Get the file stat information
file_stat = os.stat(file_path)

# Retrieve the creation and modification timestamps
creation_timestamp = file_stat.st_ctime
modification_timestamp = file_stat.st_mtime

# Convert timestamps to datetime objects
creation_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(creation_timestamp)
modification_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(modification_timestamp)

# Print the datetime information
print(f"Creation datetime: {creation_datetime}")
print(f"Modification datetime: {modification_datetime}")
```